# selenium python webdriver, how to reference element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm using webdriver/selenium, python 3x, trying to access and reference elements on a webpage:

```
<time class="MyCL" yearofbirth="1990" title="information">30 years old</time>
```

If I use any of the find_element_by_class_name - providing MyCL, or tag name giving - time:

```
value = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('MyCL')
print(value.text) #outputs 30 years old, duh, but ...
```

How do I return yearofbirth: 1990, or content of a title: "information"

Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the attribute instead of text. `text` will return innerText value of respective HTML element whereas `get_attribute` will return attribute value

```
value = driver.find_element_by_class_name('MyCL')
print(value.get_attribute('yearofbirth'))
```

Comment: It's should `.find_element`, not `.find_elements`.